# Key sequence for eclipse rcp: CTRL + Page Up or CTRL + Page Down

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

---

> Key sequence for eclipse rcp: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> means M1,

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> means M2,

But

<kbd>Page Up</kbd> means ???

<kbd>Page Down</kbd> means ???

Answer (score 2):

[org_eclipse_ui_bindings](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_bindings.html)

> The actual key is generally specified simply as the ASCII character,
>   in uppercase. So, for example F or , are examples of such keys.
>   However, there are some special keys; keys that have no printable
>   ASCII representation. The following is a list of the current special keys: ARROW_DOWN, ARROW_LEFT, ARROW_RIGHT, ARROW_UP, BREAK, BS, CAPS_LOCK, CR, DEL, END, ESC, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, FF, HOME, INSERT, LF, NUL, NUM_LOCK, NUMPAD_0, NUMPAD_1, NUMPAD_2, NUMPAD_3, NUMPAD_4, NUMPAD_5, NUMPAD_6, NUMPAD_7, NUMPAD_8, NUMPAD_9, NUMPAD_ADD, NUMPAD_DECIMAL, NUMPAD_DIVIDE, NUMPAD_ENTER, NUMPAD_EQUAL, NUMPAD_MULTIPLY, NUMPAD_SUBTRACT, **PAGE_UP**, **PAGE_DOWN**, PAUSE, PRINT_SCREEN, SCROLL_LOCK, SPACE, TAB and VT.

According to the documentation:

<kbd>Page Up</kbd> means PAGE_UP.

<kbd>Page Down</kbd> means PAGE_DOWN.

Comment: @BharatZala (Actually I just googled "eclipse rcp ctrl m1"…)